# Finding C for a PMF of a frequency distribution

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, density-function, taylor-series, frequency-severity

N has probability mass function: $p_o = p_1 =0$ and $p_k = c/k!$ for $k=2,3,4,...$ I used exp series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k!} = e^x$ to get $ c\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!}$ then $ce=1$ to get $c = 1/e$ Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you did something wrong. Look closely at what values you assumed for $p_0$ and $p_1$ when you evaluated the sum.

Comment: How would I go about this with the po p1 assumptions?

Comment: I'm not going to actually be doing your homework. What did you add to the total instead of 0+0? So exactly how much too large is your answer?